# InvalidOperationException: Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly ******, Version=1...0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PubolicKeyToken=null"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

.net core 1.1 upgraded from 1.0

In VS2015 community my app works.

In Kestrel from the command line my app works. (dotnet appName.dll)

I get the error msg (in the title) attempting to access my app on IIS server (windows10 pro).

I do not have a .csproj file I have an .xproj.

An answer by junnas to the same error msg in the title he displays the source code and what its looking for but not how to add userSecretsId without a .csproj. Without a .csproj file I crash on IIS.

junnas refrences an article and disucsion  UserSecrets: removing the dependency on project.json by natemcmasters

that article spoke about project.json as a fallback.  I have the project.json file.  It appears to create a secrets.json file but so far its empty.  A comment by smitpatel seems similar.  Though a subsequent discusson appears to pass it to rowanmiller and then to divega without offering a solution.

Kind of lost about direction from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be a userSecretsId element in project.json, ie in my app the VS Tooling automatically added it

```
"userSecretsId": "aspnet-example.WebApp-df9a79b9-e4c7-4c72-a64f-62835002c42f",
```

but if you aren't really using user secrets as a configuration store then it is easier to just remove the package reference from project.json dependencies

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.*",
```

and remove any reference to user secrets from Startup.cs, ie this:

```
builder.AddUserSecrets();
```

Comment: thanks Joe,  I am not using userSecrets I will give it a try.  Though I am still not sure why it works in the IDE and browsing Kestrel but fails on IIS.

Comment: Thanks Joe, You got me going in the right direction again.